# Odd behavior when converting strings to integers in C

Tags: c, string

Was working on a program taking a mathematical expression as a string and then evaluating it and discovered an odd behavior. Given

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int ary[4];
    char * string = "123+11";

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

        ary[i] = atoi(&string[i]);
        printf("%d\n", ary[i]);
    }

}
```

I get the output:

```
123
23
3
```

Whereas I might have expected I get the output:

```
1
2
3
```

Is this part of the `atoi()` function?

Comment: Yes! http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: You want to extract single digit? Why not just `string[i] - '0'` then? `atoi` and `strtod` parses entire string.

Comment: Remember as `atoi` is array to int and **not** ascii to int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is correct behavior because `atoi` takes a pointer to char as input and convert it into `int` till it finds "`\0`" character.

```
char * string = "123";
```

"`\0`" in string is present after 123.

For statement:

```
ary[0] = atoi(&string[0]);
```

`atoi` starts with 1 convert it to `int` till 123.

For statement:

```
ary[1] = atoi(&string[1]);
```

`atoi` starts with 2 convert it to `int` till 23.

For statement:

```
 ary[2] = atoi(&string[2]);
```

`atoi` starts with 3 convert it to `int` till 3.

Please let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: Actually, it converts until it finds a non-digit character (not necessarily a `\0`)

Comment: ^ and there is allowed to be a leading `+` or `-`

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by user3758647 is correct. To solve you problem you can use `strtok` function which tokenizes the input string based on delimiter.

```
char* string = "123+23+22";
char *token = strtok(string, "+");
int arr[4], i = 0;
arr[i] = atoi(token); //Collect first number here
while (token != NULL)
{
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    //You can collect rest of the numbers using atoi function from here
    i++;
    arr[i]  = atoi(token); 
    //Do whatever you want to do with this number here.
}
return 0;
```